# Drag two or more files attachments to dropzoneJS from Mozilla Thunderbird not working

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

DropzoneJS doesn't work after uploading 2 or more files from Mozilla Thunderbird. I get the error "Server responded with status 0 code". The console writes that provisional headers are shown.

```
      var dropzoneEdit = new Dropzone('#uploadFilesEdit', { 
            url: urlLink,
            maxFilesize: 100,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            parallelUploads: 3,
            init: function() {
                dropzone = this;
                this.on('success', function(file, response) {
                    if(typeof response.file_id != 'undefined'){
                        editedFiles = editedFiles.concat(response.file_id).unique();
                    }
                });
                this.on('successmultiple', function(file, response) {
                    if(typeof response.file_id != 'undefined'){
                        editedFiles = editedFiles.concat(response.file_id).unique();
                    }
                });
                this.on('sendingmultiple', function(file, response, test) {
                    // console.log(file, response, test);
                });
                this.on('resetFiles', function() {
                    this.removeAllFiles(true);
                    $(this.element).removeClass('dz-started').find('.dz-preview').remove();
                    this.files.length = 0;
                    editedFiles = [];
                });
                this.on('complete', function() {
                    if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
                        this.processQueue();
                    }
                });
                this.on('queuecomplete', function() {
                    editDamage();
                });
                this.on('addedfile', function(file, response) {
                    if(typeof file.file_id != 'undefined'){
                        $(file.previewElement).addClass('dz-success').find('.dz-progress').css('opacity', '0');
                        this.files.push({name: file.name, size: file.size, file_id: file.file_id});
                    } else {
                        // console.log(file, response);
                    }
                });
                this.on('drop', function(file, response) {
                    console.log(response, file);
                });
                this.on('removedfile', function(file) {
                    let index = editedFiles.indexOf(file.file_id);
                    if (index > -1) {
                        editedFiles.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                    if (editedFiles.length === 0) {
                        this.removeAllFiles(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This is the answer I received in Google Chrome:

```
Request URL: http://localhost/project/send-files
Referrer Policy: no-referrer
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9xWdzyGc6PdshRA1
Referer
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
file[0]: (binary)
file[1]: (binary)
```

Is this the fault of mozilla thunderbird files location?
It works very well with program Outlook. Problem only with Mozilla Thunderbird...